# request_oauth using twitter (C#)

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the following code in an attempt to get oauth_token and oauth_secret.

```
        string url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
        string base_format = "oauth_callback={0}&oauth_consumer_key={1}&oauth_nonce={2}&oauth_signature_method={3}&oauth_timestamp={4}&oauth_version={5}";
        string base_string = String.Format(base_format, oauth_callback, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_version);
        base_string = String.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(url), Uri.EscapeDataString(base_string));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                    "&");

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base_string)));
        }
        string header_format = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_callback=\"{1}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{2}\", oauth_timestamp=\"{3}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", oauth_version=\"{6}\"";
        string header = string.Format(header_format, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_callback), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version));

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

and its returning me a 401. I fail to see what wrong here. Help is required.

Comment: You are not signing the request. You need to encrypt the information you are sending along and include that as the signature. This code is far to simple for what you are wanting to accomplish. Doing it by hand this way will make your life a headache, though sometimes it is required to write your own. You can find out more about signing here http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process

Comment: Thank you i have succeeded. There were a few format problems with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your life so much easier. I have used it before and it takes care of everything.
http://www.twitterizer.net

Comment: Sorry my project can't use any 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the OAuthTokenSecret to your composite key.

**Working example**

```
public string UpdateStatus(string status)
{
    var oauth_version = "1.0";
    var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

    // unique request details
    var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(
        (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
            .TotalSeconds).ToString();

    var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

    // create oauth signature
    var baseString = string.Format(
        "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&" +
        "oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}",
        config.OAuthConsumerKey,
        oauth_nonce,
        oauth_signature_method,
        oauth_timestamp,
        config.OAuthToken,
        oauth_version,
        Uri.EscapeDataString(status));


    baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

    var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(config.OAuthConsumerSecret),
    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(config.OAuthTokenSecret));

    string oauth_signature;
    using (var hasher = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
    {
        oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
    }

    // create the request header
    var authHeader = string.Format(
        "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\"," +
        " oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\", " +
        "oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\",  oauth_token=\"{5}\", " +
        "oauth_version=\"{6}\"",
        Uri.EscapeDataString(config.OAuthConsumerKey),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(config.OAuthToken),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
    );


    var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream reqStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reqStreamReader = new StreamReader(reqStream);
        return reqStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex + ":\n" + ex.Message;
    }
}
```